# actual props not render (react)

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm trying to render actual data in child component, but data does not render. What is wrong?

**Parent component**

```
const UserPanelContainer = ({ currentUser }) => {
  

const [initUsersData, setinitUsersData] = useState(currentUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect')
    setinitUsersData(()=>getnewData())
  }, [setinitUsersData, currentUser])

const getnewData = () =>{
  console.log('getnewData')
  setinitUsersData(currentUser)
}

  return (
    
  <UserPanel currentUser={initUsersData} hanleOnClickOut={hanleOnClickOut} >{console.log('usepanContainerRender')}</UserPanel>
    
  );
};

export default UserPanelContainer;
```

**child**

```
    const UserPanel = ({ currentUser, hanleOnClickOut }) => {
    
    console.log(currentUser);
  return (
     <div className="dropdown">
        {console.log('userPanelRender')}
      <button
        className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        id="dropdownMenuButton"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        <img
          className="avatar"
          src={currentUser.photoURL}
          alt="avatar"
        />
        {currentUser.displayName}
      </button>
      <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <div className="dropdown-item">
          Вошел как {currentUser.displayName}
        </div>
        <div className="dropdown-item" onClick={hanleOnClickOut}>
          Выйти
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserPanel;
```

In console in child I can see correct actual data in props, but they are not rendered.
Actual data contains "currentUser" prop. But on Browser page i cant see data....
(if i delete currentUser from useEffect depencity i can see data from previus API call)

Comment: Children don't update when their props change.  You have to use their state.  Add the props data in state and change the state when needed, this will update the component

Comment: What did you get in child component when you console it ?

Comment: @Woops they actually do rerender when props change

Comment: @ Woops if you mean like this - dont work also  
 const [initUsersDatainChild, setinitUsersDatainChild] = useState(''); 
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect')
        setinitUsersDatainChild(currentUser)
      }, [ currentUser])

Comment: @Garsivirus  - i got actual data for render

Answer (score 0):

I see you are passing the `setinitUsersData` in the `useEffect` dependency array whereas you need to pass the actual state variable

try this,

```
useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, [initUsersData, currentUser])
```

instead of current,

```
useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, [setinitUsersData, currentUser])
```

Comment: **@Rejo Chandran** befor passing data in child - i get data from server, after set it in redux store, after get accses from connect and pass to props - if this info can help And if i refresh page or do something what made render - after that data already was rendered.

Comment: **@Rejo Chandran** i tryed it also - i changed set func to value - dont work

Answer (score 0):

I think by actual data you mean some api response.

Try this :-

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect')
    getnewData(currentUser)
  }, [currentUser])

const getnewData = (currentUser) =>{
  console.log('getnewData')
  axios.get("/pathToData").then((res) => {
   console.log(res);
   setinitUsersData(res);
  })

}
```

Comment: **@deepakgupta191199** no, API response i got and this data come after API call from redux store. Like this schema (call API -> redux -> parent props -> child props (and child props i got in child prop (in console i see it), but not on browser page)

Comment: Try commenting the useEffect code and pass currentUser in the child component directly.

Comment: **@deepakgupta191199** in this case  i have not render also

Answer (score 0):

Replace parent component with the following code. You don't need to use `useEffect` as per the code you've posted. Since parent is already receiving `currentUser` and you have already updated state with that

```
const UserPanelContainer = ({ currentUser }) => {
  const [initUsersData, setinitUsersData] = useState(currentUser);
  return (<UserPanel 
   currentUser={initUsersData} 
   hanleOnClickOut={hanleOnClickOut}>{console.log('usepanContainerRender')}</UserPanel>
  );
};

export default UserPanelContainer;
```

Comment: **@SaachiTech** in this case i have child prop with previos data

Comment: **@ALL** if i inspect data cicle in inspect mode chrome (with breakpoins) - all works fine and i got good result

Comment: How about setting `currentUser={currentUser}`?

Comment: **@SaachiTech** in this case we go initional condition - props actual but not shown on page

Comment: Not sure I get it. Could you please setup a snack to reproduce your issue?

Comment: **@SaachiTech** What do you mean - "setup a snack"? Expo Snack?

Comment: on this link it work fine - you can see picture on button. in my case i dont see it. I think need more info about redux data and API call, but in so match info...